Electron Forge app works in development but not after packaging
I'm using Electron Forge to build my Electron application. The app runs perfectly in development mode using electron-forge start, but after packaging it with electron-forge package or electron-forge make, the application does not start, and there are no error messages or logs to indicate what went wrong. It seems like the main.js file is not being called at all. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?
The application runs without any issues in development mode.
After packaging, the application does not start, and there is no error output.
Logging in the main.js file does not seem to be executed.
I've checked the package.json configuration to ensure the main field points to the correct entry file.
I have tried disabling the asar option in the packagerConfig.
I have added extensive logging to the main.js file to capture any errors, but it appears that the file is not being executed at all.
The file structure seems correct, and all necessary files are included in the packaged output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
